# EKF SLAM : SLAM specific Jacobians for new landmarks

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, kalman-filter, ekf, jacobian

I am currently trying to understand the books **[SLAM for dummies](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/119149/16-412j-spring-2005/contents/projects/1aslam_blas_repo.pdf)** and **[Simulataneous localization and mapping
with the extended Kalman filter](http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/curs_SLAM/SLAM2D/SLAM%20course.pdf)** to implement slam. I have understood steps 1 and 2 **SLAM for dummies**. However I am having difficulty understanding ***Step 3: Add new landmarks to the current state*** (Page 40). The corresponding section in **Simulataneous localization and mapping
with the extended Kalman filter** is **2.3.4 Landmark initialization for full observations**.

Specifically, I do not understand how the SLAM specific Jacobian $J_{xr}$ (**SLAM for dummies**) defined below is actually derived:

[image]

[image]

I am confused about what transformation function the Jacobian $J_{xr}$ is linearizing. I notice that $J_{xr}$ is the same as Jacobian $G_R$ that linearizes the Inverse Observation model as described in section 2.3.4 of **Simulataneous localization and mapping
with the extended Kalman filter**. Why does $J_{xr}$, contain $\Delta t$, which is the thrust applied to the robot? $\Delta t$ which belongs to the State Prediction model shouldn't be in the Inverse Observation model, no? Am I right to say that the Inverse Observation model is a function of the robot pose : [$x_{r}$, $y_{r}$, $\theta_{r}$] and the new landmark observation:  [$d_{l1}$, $\phi_{l1}$] and the output is the updated state vector : [$x_{r}$, $y_{r}$, $\theta_{r}$, $x_{l1}$, $y_{l1}$]?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the covariance matrix for a new landmark always confused me, the equation is often given but I've never seen it derived.  I had a go at deriving it here

http://petercorke.com/wordpress/ekf-covariance-matrix-update-for-a-new-landmark

I'd be interested to know if you find this useful.

Comment: That helped me understand the Jacobians. Thank you!